# botocore hangs and goes very slow when running `get_object` twice in the same async function

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, python-asyncio

I'm using `aiobotocore` and `asyncio` to read objects from S3.

I'm creating my session before the loop with:

```python
client = aiobotocore.get_session(...).session.create_client('s3', ...)
```

Then I define my async function:

```
async def go(client):
    resp = await client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    file_size = resp['ContentLength']

    resp = await client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range='bytes=1000-2000')

    await resp['Body'].read()  # just read for testing
```

And run the function 100 times:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[go(client) for i in range(100)]))
```

This hangs and produces errors such as:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerTimeoutError: Timeout on reading data from socket
```

But if I simply remove the first `get_object` where I'm reading the `ContentLength`, I can run 1000 instances without any problem. This runs fine:

```
async def go(client):
    resp = await client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range='bytes={}-{}'.format(1000, 3000))

    await resp['Body'].read()  # just read for testing
```

I don't understand why two `get_object` calls would behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `.get_object()` call is pulling down in the entire file. I’m guessing these files are not trivial in size and so pulling down 100 of them at the same time is more than your internet connection can handle and some of these are timing out.  If your just after the file size call `head_object()` which will get you the same info without the expense of pulling down the whole thing.

Comment: I did a timing, the bulk of the time doesn't get counted until resp['Body'].read() is called. I thought this was effectively just head, but I'll try that shortly.